# the if statement in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a question about if statement in tcl of the following code:

```
if {(($number == 1)&&($name == "hello")) || (($number == 0)&&($name == "yes"))} {
    #do something here
}
```

The above code works, but if I wrote it down like this:

```
if {{$number == 1 && $name == "hello"} || {$number == 0&&$name == "yes"}} {
    #do something here
}
```

It complains that the `$number` is expected to be a boolean, why? Is the second one not a valid expression? How to correct it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Braces, `{}`, and parentheses, `()`, are *not* interchangeable in Tcl.

Formally, braces are (with [one exception](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17158)) a kind of quoting that indicates that no further substitutions are to be performed on the contents. In the first case above, this means that that argument is delivered to `if` without substitution, which evaluates it as an expression. The expression sub-language has a strongly-analogous brace interpretation scheme to general Tcl; they denote a literal value with no further substitutions to perform on it.

By contrast, parentheses are mostly not special in Tcl. The exceptions are in the names of elements of arrays (e.g., `$foo(bar)`), in the expression sublanguage (which uses them for grouping, as in mathematical expressions all over programming) and in the regular expression sublanguage (where they are a different type of grouping and a few other things). It is entirely legal to use parentheses — balanced or otherwise — as part of a command name in Tcl, but you might have your fellow programmers complaining at you anyway for writing confusing code.

### The Specifics

In this specific case, the test expression of this `if`:

```
if {{$number == 1 && $name == "hello"} || {$number == 0&&$name == "yes"}} {...}
```

is parsed into:

```
blah#1 LOGICAL_OR blah#2
```

where each `blah` is a literal. Unfortunately, `blah#1` (which is exactly equal to `$number == 1 && $name == "hello"`) has no boolean interpretation. (Nor does `blah#2` but we never bother to consider that.) Things are definitely going very wrong here!

The simplest fix is to change those bogus braces back to parentheses:

```
if {($number == 1 && $name == "hello") || ($number == 0&&$name == "yes")} {...}
```

I bet this is what you originally wanted.

### Warning: Advanced Topic

However, the other fix is to add in a little extra:

```
if {[expr {$number == 1 && $name == "hello"}] || [expr {$number == 0&&$name == "yes"}]} {...}
```

This is normally not a good idea — extra bulk for no extra gain — but it makes sense where you're trying to use a dynamically-generated expression as a test condition. ***Do not do this*** unless you're really really certain you need to do this! I mean it. It's a very advanced technique that you hardly ever need, and there's often a better way to do your overall goal. If you think you *might* need it, for goodness' sake ask here on SO and we'll try to find a better way; there's almost always one available.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message you are getting does not mean that `$number` has to be a boolean (I got the message `expected boolean value but got "$number == 1 && $name == "hello""`).
It means that the string `$number == 1 && $name == "hello"` is not a boolean value - which is definitely true.
If you use curly braces in your `if` expression those strings are not evaluated but are simply interpreted as they are - as a string of characters.

Comment: @ratzip The first one looks fine. It has more parentheses than you strictly need, but they don't hurt in expressions as they're compiled out.

Answer (score 1):

In short: `if` uses a special "mini language" for its condition script — the same understood by the [`expr` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm).  This is stated in the [`if` manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/if.htm):

> The if command evaluates expr1 as an expression (in the same way that expr evaluates its argument).

In contrast to Tcl itself, which is quite LISP-like and/or Unix shell-like, that "`expr` mini language" is way more "traditional" in the sense it feels like C.

Answer (score 1):

In `($number == 1)` number is assigned 1 and the comparison is made.Ex: `1==1` here output is Boolean.
But in `{$number == 1 && $name == "hello"}` $number is not assigned because of flower bracket `$number` is compared with `1` so output obtained is not Boolean.