# How Tcl parses whitespace within parentheses in an If statement

Tags: tcl, parentheses, braces

I understand that the if statement in Tcl requires braces `{ }` instead of parentheses `( )`.

However, the following (erroneous) code prints `"Aha!"` because Tcl seems to be able to interpret the if condition correctly:

```
set flow_control 1
if ($flow_control==1) {
    puts "Aha!"
}
```

Yet the following (with spaces) fails with 'unbalanced open paren in expression "(1"'

```
set flow_control 1
if ($flow_control == 1) {
    puts "Aha!"
}
```

And of course, using braces either with or without parentheses, with or without spaces works:

```
set flow_control 1
if {$flow_control == 1} {
    puts "Braces rule!"
}
```

My question is, why does the second case fail?

Donal Fellows' answer to [the if statement in TCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260659/the-if-statement-in-tcl) explains clearly the difference between braces and parentheses but I can't figure out why whitespace causes the second block to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Braces are a quoting mechanism that groups several words into a single word. Refer to the [12 syntax rules](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Note carefully the syntax of the [`if`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/if.htm) command:

```
if expr1 ?then? body1 elseif expr2 ?then? body2 elseif ... ?else? ?bodyN?
```

`expr1` must be a single word.

`{ $foo == $bar }` is a single word due to the braces

`($flowcontrol == 1)` has no braces or double quotes, so it is parsed as 3 separate words. The first word's variable is expanded and then the word is given to `if` as the `expr1`, and `(1` is not a valid expression.

`($flowcontrol==1)` without spaces is a single word. The variable is expanded and then `(1==1)` -- a valid expression -- is given to `if`.